# Jaxb Moxy with Hibernate? on Jboss 6.1

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, jaxb, moxy

Is it possible to use Moxy With Hibernate?

And if so how do i install it, have tried to find documentation of it but found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) to map any POJOs to XML.  As EclipseLink also offers a world class JPA implementation, we are very familiar with the needs of mapping POJOs used with object-relational mapping tools.

**MOXy** offers many extensions for mapping JPA entities including support for bidirectional relationships and composite keys:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA

**EclipseLink** is offered as both a JAR and as OSGi enabled bundles.  The one you need will depend on your environment (can you provide additional details?):

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

**MOXy** is now the default JAXB provider in **WebLogic 12c**, so if you are using this environment there is nothing you need to do to install MOXy:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html

If you are using **GlassFish**, then the following article will help you with the setup ([MOXy is be included in **GlassFish** starting in version 3.1.2](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/glassfish-312-is-full-of-moxy.html)):

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

**UPDATE**

To get just the **MOXy** piece of **EclipseLink** you can OSGi bundles (from the URL below):

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

And include the following bundles on your class path:

- org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_???.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.core_???.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.asm_???.jar

Comment: Hi i develop in Seam 2.2.2 with Jboss 6.1, when i added Eclipslink.jar to my project my entitymanagers stoped working :/ do i need the whole eclipslink implementation to use moxy?

Comment: How do i download just Moxy? and not the whole EclipseLink?

Comment: @Trind - I updated my answer with instructions for just including the MOXy portion of EclipseLink.

Comment: @Trind - No problem, please let me know if that fixes the issue that you are seeing.